# Last element's margin-bottom wont stretch its container

Tags: html, css

I wonder why `.content-b`  's margin-bottom wont stretch the `.container` ?

```css
.container {
  background: grey;
}

.content-a,
.content-b {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content-a"></div>
  <div class="content-b"></div>
</div>
```

If you inspect `.content-b` you can see that the browser renders the margin, and would push down the elements below it if there were any, but shouldn't it stretch the container itself?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ymhn7dtz/1)

Comment: No, it shouldn't, because of how margin collapsing works. You can use `overflow: auto` or similar tricks to force a new context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `overflow: auto;` to your `container`:

```css
  .container {
  background: grey;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content-a,
.content-b {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content-a"></div>
  <div class="content-b"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a `margin` would make it simply just overflow.

The default value of `overflow` is `visible`, meaning it will be displayed outside of the container, and your `margin` doesn't have a background colour.

give your `container` an `overflow: auto` property would do